# Style a select to show values on left and right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello everyone do any of you have an idea how to style a dropdown similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRM0y.png)? Using jQuery or any other library. Basically, to have a value on the left, and also on the right. I've looked it up and it seems that you are not allowed to put any other elements inside an **option** tag.

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Can you show us what you have actually tried?

Comment: That's not  a select tag, they've rebuilt the control from scratch using other elements.  You could use a ul/li's to build the list and use a div for the main element.  Then you have to write all the CSS and JS/jQuery to handle the mouse, hovering, keyboard shortcuts, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can't do it with `select` element, you must create it with ul and li, and also help of jquery.

**Like this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.txt,span').click(function(){
    $('ul').toggle();
})
  $('li').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).html();
    $('.txt').html(text);
    $('ul').hide();
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width : 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.txt {
  width: 95%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  width:100%;
}

li {
 width:100%;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  top: 0;
} 
.txt b,li b {
    float: right;
} 

b {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="txt"></div><span>▾</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Instalation full Service<b>299.00THB</b></li>
    <li>Other instalation full Service<b>300.00THB</b></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar being done with MaterializeCSS, check out the following link, go to the section for **Badges in Dropdown**:
http://materializecss.com/badges.html

Some similar stuff is available in:
http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html#!
as well.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery UI, they have a `select` style menu that you can customize:

> Selectmenu
>
> Duplicates and extends the functionality of a native HTML select
>   element to overcome the limitations of the native control.

https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render